# Exist something better to make this?

Tags: jquery

Exist something better to make this? With fewer lines?

```
$('#hider').click(function(){
    $(".name_A").hide();
    $(".name_B").hide();
    $(".name_C").hide();        
    });
```

I want to put many names, A, B, C, (100 names) ... and hide with a button only 50.

I'm new on JQuery. I have been tried filter but does't work good for me.

Comment: just use startswith selector : $('[class^=name_]').hide(); This would hide all elements having class starts with 'name_'

Comment: @DinoMyte Unless the rest of the 50 does not start with `name` which does not need to be hidden. Also, it will depend if this convention is just for sample or are they actual classnames used

Comment: @Nimesh: OP did not mention which 50 he wants to hide. So I'll go with the assumption based on what he specified in the code that he wants to hide the elements which have the class with pattern 'name_[alphabet]'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can separate multiple class names using `,`

```
$('#hider').click(function(){
    $(".name_A, .name_B, .name_C").hide();
});
```

But having 100 different classnames and then hiding 50 of them by naming them individually, is it correct programming?
In CSS, you can assign multiple class names to an element too, I hope you are doing it right.

**Note:** I don't know if there is any better solution than this without knowing the details of related HTML/CSS.

You can refer the below link for more help on jQuery Selectors
[W3Schools - jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: You can simply use starts with selector to avoid declaring the individual selectors , $('[class^=name_]').hide()

Comment: @DinoMyte Thanks for sharing this, haven't used this so didn't noticed it. Anyway I've added the link which covers more details so the OP can check and apply as per his use.

Comment: It's really simple code that I need, it's working, but there are many lines. 
Your way is much better. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @user2992376 I'm sorry, but that is not better. Hard coding 100 classes is a very bad practice. What if they change in the future? And it also takes for ever. Maintenance will be hard and painful.

Comment: @user2992376 If you can provide more details about HTML and CSS we can come up with better answer which will help you and anyone in future working on the project, for code review and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I need more details to answer your question better. What does your HTML look like? What 50 do you want to hide? The first 50 or the last 50?

In the mean time, here is what you could do both:

HTML example:

```
<button id="hide-btn">Hide 50 names</button>
<ul class='name-list'>
    <li>Name 1</li>
    <li>Name 2</li>
    <li>Name 3</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

JavaScript example:

```
var $hideFirstBtn = $( '#hide-first-btn' ),
        $hideLastBtn = $( '#hide-last-btn' ),
        $nameList = $( '.name-list' ),
        $nameListLength = $nameList.find( 'li' ).length;

$hideFirstBtn.on( 'click', function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
        $nameList.find( 'li' ).eq( i ).hide();
    }
});

$hideLastBtn.on( 'click', function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 51; i++ ) {
        $nameList.find( 'li' ).eq( $nameListLength - i ).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, .hide() is work more simple, and I want to keep code simple. To work with fo (var i= 0) etc is not working for me yet... But thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean `for (var i - 0)` does not work for you yet?